# Resolving DNS adress after proxy in SSH.NET

Tags: c#, networking, proxy, dns, ssh.net

I'm using **SSH.Net** in C# and during connection behind a SOCKS5 proxy, I get the following exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.ConnectSocks5()
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
```

Connection from the same machine behind the same proxy to the same server  is working seamlessly with **WinScp** with the **Do DNS name lookup at proxy end** option selected in the site settings:

[image]

Is there a way to tell SSH.Net to do the same ?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem to be possible.

SSH.NET is always [doing DNS resolving locally](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/2016.1.0/src/Renci.SshNet/Session.cs#L2053):

```
var ip = DnsAbstraction.GetHostAddresses(ConnectionInfo.Host)[0];

//  Send address type and address
if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
    SocketWriteByte(0x01);
    var address = ip.GetAddressBytes();
    SocketAbstraction.Send(_socket, address);
}
else if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
{
    SocketWriteByte(0x04);
    var address = ip.GetAddressBytes();
    SocketAbstraction.Send(_socket, address);
}
else
{
    throw new ProxyException(string.Format("SOCKS5: IP address '{0}' is not supported.", ip));
}
```

If you are willing to modify SSH.NET code, you need to replace the code with something like (untested):

```
// Send address type and address

SocketWriteByte(0x03); // Resolve by proxy

var host = SshData.Ascii.GetBytes(ConnectionInfo.Host);

SocketWriteByte((byte)host.Length);

SocketAbstraction.Send(_socket, host);
```

What should be an equivalent of [this PuTTY/WinSCP code](https://github.com/winscp/winscp/blob/5.13.5/source/putty/proxy.c#L817):

```c
assert(type == ADDRTYPE_NAME);
command[3] = 3;
sk_getaddr(p->remote_addr, command+5, 256);
command[4] = strlen(command+5);
len = 7 + command[4];  /* 4 hdr, 1 len, N addr, 2 trailer */
```

Comment: A pull request has been created which adds this, but I've not tested it. I'm testing it now: https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/pull/77